# Node JS Puppeteer click on a li element without name or id

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to click on a li element which for some reason works as a size selector on a certain website. It looks like this

[image: size selector]

And its html looks like this

[image]

Each `<li>` represents one size option, I've tried some stuff but none of it works.

my first attempt was using xpath:

```
const [size_button] = await page.$x(`//*[contains(., '${data[ii][1]}')]`); // doesn't work
await size_button.click();
```

I also tried a regular click action:

```
await page.click(`li[data-original-title="Größe in EU: ${data[ii][1]}"]`); // the array contains a specific size, eg. 40.5 like in the li data-original-title field
```

None of this worked, and I'm wondering if it is even possible to click on such a element with puppeteer...

If anyone would like to examine the page, the link is [here](https://en.afew-store.com/products/air-jordan-4-retro-tour-yellow-dark-blue-grey-white)

Comment: Try using this selector: `.size-picker > ul > li:nth-child(2)`

Comment: The xpath/selector works fine (although OP really should show `data` in the interests of a [mcve]...), it's the clicking that seems to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. Your selector is working OK, as is the click event, but I suspect that event does nothing but call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent navigation to the anchor's href.

The highlight showing the size was selected is actually applied by a `mousedown` event in the `<a>`'s parent `<li>`, and it seems the child event hasn't been applied or doesn't bubble using your `.click` method:

[image: image showing browser console element tree with the li element's mousedown event circled to indicate it's the important event OP wants to trigger]

You can trigger this as follows:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^13.5.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", req => {
    req.resourceType() === "image" ? req.abort() : req.continue();
  });
  const url = "https://en.afew-store.com/products/air-jordan-4-retro-tour-yellow-dark-blue-grey-white";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const size = "8.5";
  const xp = `//a[contains(@class, "btn-sm") and text()="${size}"]`;
  const sizeButton = await page.waitForXPath(xp);
  await sizeButton.evaluate(btn => {
    btn.closest("li").dispatchEvent(new Event("mousedown"));
    //  ^--- .parentNode is also possible instead of .closest("li")
  });
  await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

The final timeout gives you a chance to look at the page and see that size 8.5 was highlighted.

Note that I've made your xpath selector more precise to avoid false positives.

Comment: wow, that actually works, thank you for your time and the detail you went to about your answer. I wouldn't have figured to opt for a mousedown myself, thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could for instance get al <a tags with the class="btn btn-sm"

I think is a good idea get the expected result in the console of the browser using Vainilla Javascript, and when suscess try to reach the same result with Puppeteer

- Vainilla Javascript

  ```
   const sizeLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a.btn.btn-sm')
   sizeLinks[1].click()
  ```
- Puppeteer (Full working example)

  ```
    'use strict'

     const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async () => {
       const baseUrl = 'https://en.afew-store.com/products/air-jordan-4-retro-tour-yellow-dark-blue-grey-white'

       const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); // default is true

       const page = await browser.newPage();
       await page.goto(baseUrl, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
       });

        await page.waitForTimeout(5000) // Leave extra time for complete the page load (Just to be cautious)

        const sizeLinks = await page.$$('a.btn.btn-sm')
        await sizeLinks[1].click() 

        console.log('Debugging')

        //await browser.close();
        //console.log(`Browser has been closed`);

        //process.exit(0);
  })();
  ```
- Reference:

[JavaScript querySelector() and querySelectorAll()](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-queryselector/)

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me in Puppeteer. Do you have complete, runnable code I can simply execute to see that this works? I suspect the page's click events on the `<a>` just block the default behavior, and that triggering `mousedown` on the parent `<li>` is what would highlight it correctly.

Comment: @ggorlen I edit the post and add a full working example

Comment: Thanks. I ran the code and I don't see it highlighting the size though. BTW, it's not a good idea to use `waitForTimeout` -- this is a race condition that slows down your scrape at best, and at worst gives a false negative. Better to use `waitForSelector` which will spawn a tight polling loop and can be adjsuted to wait as long as necessary, but no longer.

Comment: @ggorlen I edit the post and add an image, just wait a few seconds.

By the way waitForSelector  is similar to what is next: await page.$$()

So I specify that I am using waitForTimeout  just to be cautious.

Comment: Interesting -- it seems to work fairly consistently but I'm getting redirected to https://en.afew-store.com/ every few attempts. Strange, it doesn't seem fundamentally different from OP's `.click()`. `page.$$` doesn't wait for anything as far as I know, just runs `document.querySelectorAll` immediately. Since you're using the very conservative `networkidle2` the selector would generally be ready by then. Why is it that running your `querySelectorAll` in the console, nothing is clicked for me?

Comment: @ggorlen You are right page.$$ doesn't wait for anything, also the browser, querySelectorAll returned the NodeList but now the click in the element it is not working also for me (Previously it works ok).

Comment: Yeah, something's going on... Your (and OP's) approach _should work_ -- it's the normal way to do this, so I'm perplexed as to the inconsistency. My answer is more of a workaround, so I'm really curious what's going on. Usually, if something can't be clicked, it's a visibility problem that can be handled with `e.evaluate(e => e.click())`, or it's a frame problem or shadow DOM, but none are the case here. Could be a delayed event listener.

Comment: @ggorlen I also clicked in the button Accept All Cookies to ensure that it was not the case 